# convert exponential to decimal in python

Tags: python, unix, awk, exponent

I have an array in python that contains a set of values, some of them are

2.32313e+07

2.1155e+07

1.923e+07

11856

112.32

How do I convert the exponential formats to the decimal format

Additional: Is there a way I can convert the exponent directly to decimal when printing out in UNIX with awk?

Comment: do you want to convert to string representing a float with certain precision?

Comment: yes. And the precision can be any number

Comment: what does *any number* mean? do you know this number?

Comment: the number would depend on the type of file that i am extracting this info from. I would know this number beforehand

Comment: See this recent question for a similar problem and an interesting solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine you have a list rather than an array, but here it doesn't make much of a difference; in 2.6 and earlier versions of Python, something like:

```
>>> L = [2.32313e+07, 2.1155e+07, 1.923e+07, 11856, 112.32]
>>> for x in L: print '%f' % x
... 
23231300.000000
21155000.000000
19230000.000000
11856.000000
112.320000
```

and in 2.6 or later, the `.format` method.  I imagine you are aware that the numbers per se, as numbers, aren't in any "format" -- it's the *strings* you obtain by formatting the numbers, e.g. for output, that are in some format.  BTW, variants on that `%f` can let you control number of decimals, width, alignment, etc -- hard to suggest exactly what you may want without further specs from you.

In awk, you can use [printf](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_7.html#SEC60).

Answer (score 1):

You can use locale.format() to format your numbers for output. This has the additional benefit of being consistent with any locale-specific conventions that might be expected in the presentation of the numbers. If you want complete control at the specific place where you do the output, you'd be better of with the *print "format" % vars...* [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573080/convert-exponential-to-decimal-in-python/1573115#1573115).

Example:

```
>>> import locale 
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
'C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C'
>>> locale.format("%f", 2.32313e+07, 1)
'23231300.000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the last part of your question, `awk` can use the same `printf` format:

```
awk '{printf "%f\n",$1}' exponential_file
```

Where exponential_file contains:

```
2.32313e+07
2.1155e+07
1.923e+07
11856
112.32
```

You can do the conversion into a variable for use later. Here is a simplistic example:

```
awk '{n = sprintf("%f\n",$1); print n * 2}' exponential_file
```