# subclassing float to force fixed point printing precision in python

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.x, subclass, built-in-types

**[Python 3.1]**

I'm following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python/1567630#1567630):

```
class prettyfloat(float):
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%0.2f" % self
```

I know I need to keep track of my float literals (i.e., replace `3.0` with  `prettyfloat(3.0)`, etc.), and that's fine.

But whenever I do any calculations, `prettyfloat` objects get converted into `float`.

What's the easiest way to fix it?

EDIT:

I need exactly two decimal digits; and I need it across the whole code, including where I print a dictionary with `float` values inside. That makes any formatting functions hard to use.

I can't use `Decimal` global setting, since I want computations to be at full precision (just printing at 2 decimal points).

@Glenn Maynard: I agree I shouldn't override `__repr__`; if anything, it would be just `__str__`. But it's a moot point because of the following point.

@Glenn Maynard and @singularity: I won't subclass `float`, since I agree it will look very ugly in the end.

I will stop trying to be clever, and just call a function everywhere a `float` is being printed. Though I am really sad that I can't override `__str__` in the builtin class `float`.

Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way to format nicely may be to use `decimal.Decimal`.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: I've yet to see a case where subclassing a core type like `float` is the right thing to do.

Comment: @S.Lott I need exactly two decimal digits; and I need it across the whole code, including where I print a dictionary with float values inside.

@Glenn Maynard I don't have much hope, either :( Just thought maybe there's a clean way to make it work.

Comment: Having the `repr` of a class round the value is wrong behavior and may break things in strange and subtle ways, because Python code is supposed to be able to depend on `eval(repr(1.12345))` being a round-trip operation.  `repr` is the wrong place to be handling formatting.

Comment: Please **update** your question to include all the facts.  Please don't add comments to a question which you own.  Please **update** the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at the answer you followed up on, and I think you're confusing *data* and its *representation*.

@Robert Rossney suggested to subclass `float` so you could [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) an iterable of standard, non-adulterated `floats` into `prettyfloats` *for display purposes*:

```
# Perform all our computations using standard floats.
results = compute_huge_numbers(42)
# Switch to prettyfloats for printing.
print(map(prettyfloat, results))
```

In other words, you were not supposed to (and you shouldn't) use `prettyfloat` as a replacement for `float` everywhere in your code.

Of course, inheriting from `float` to solve that problem is overkill, since it's a representation problem and not a data problem. A simple function would be enough:

```
def prettyfloat(number):
    return "%0.2f" % number  # Works the same.
```

Now, if it's not about representation after all, and what you actually want to achieve is fixed-point *computations* limited to two decimal places everywhere in your code, that's [another story](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) entirely.

Answer (score 3):

that because `prettyfloat (op) prettyfloat` don't return a `prettyfloat`

example:

```
>>> prettyfloat(0.6)
0.60  # type prettyfloat
>>> prettyfloat(0.6) + prettyfloat(4.4)
5.0  # type float
```

solution if you don't want to cast every operation result manually to `prettyfloat` and **if you still want to use `prettyfloat`** is to override all operators.

example with operator `__add__` (which is ugly)

```
class prettyfloat(float):
  def __repr__(self):
      return "%0.2f" % self
  def __add__(self, other):
      return prettyfloat(float(self) + other)

>>> prettyfloat(0.6) + prettyfloat(4.4)
5.00
```

by doing this i think you will have also to change the name from `prettyfloat` to `uglyfloat` :) , Hope this will help

Comment: As an example of the sort of gotcha you'll hit with this sort of thing, the results of `prettyfloat(1.12345) + 1.12345` and `1.12345 + prettyfloat(1.12345)` are very different.

Comment: yeap that why he shouldn't do it, he can make it more uglier by doing some type check each time to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `decimal`. This is what it's for.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 2
>>> one = decimal.Decimal("1.0")
>>> three = decimal.Decimal("3.0")
>>> one / three
Decimal('0.33')
```

...unless you actually want to work with full-precision floats everywhere in your code but print them rounded to two decimal places. In that case, you need to rewrite your printing logic.

Comment: This is changing the precision of the value, not just how it's displayed, which is very different.  I also have to seriously question the design competence of a module with global configuration.  If you use a library (or several) which uses this module behind the scenes, it's hard to imagine the number of obscure and hard-to-fix ways you could be bitten by context configuration changes.

Comment: (I wish they'd fix the site bug that lets people edit answers without them showing up as edited.)

Comment: @Glenn: I believe there's a short window after posting where you can edit without marking your post as edited. You are indeed correct, of course =).