# Having problems with python rounding numbers when I call a specific entity from an array

Tags: python, list, rounding

I have an array:

```
a = [0.313767818199811, 0.169656461527218, 0.934219696497667]
```

When I do

```
print a
[0.313767818199811, 0.169656461527218, 0.934219696497667]

print a[0]
0.3137678182
```

I need to preserve all the digits of each number in an array. I need `a[0]` to equal `0.313767818199811`

Whats the best way to tell python to preserve the digits?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Deserves down vote for bad research.

Comment: @jvallver: Try running this code:
a = [0.313767818199811, 0.169656461527218, 0.934219696497667]
print a
print a[0]

Comment: `repr` returns the shortest string that rounds back to the original `float`, which could be from 1 to 17 digits, e.g. `0.10000000000000002` needs 17 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
print '%.15f' % a[0]
>> 0.313767818199811
```

It will display 15 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 4):

`a[0]` does equal the full expansion. The print statement is truncating it (using `str`) for display purposes.

The following code might make this clearer. In particular, it explains the discrepancy between printing `a` and `a[0]` — `str(a)` calls `repr` (not `str`) on the elements of `a`:

```
>>> str(a)
'[0.313767818199811, 0.169656461527218, 0.934219696497667]'
>>> str(a[0])
'0.3137678182'

>>> repr(a)
'[0.313767818199811, 0.169656461527218, 0.934219696497667]'
>>> repr(a[0])
'0.313767818199811'
```

As suggested in the above code, you can display `a[0]` with the full precision as follows:

```
>>> print repr(a[0])
0.313767818199811
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get the print statement to not do this?

Comment: @user1808562: I've just amended my answer with a way to display the full expansion.

Comment: @user1808562 just do `print repr(a[0])`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python

Answer (score 0):

you may need `repr()` here, `print` uses `str()` so your output is truncated:

```
In [13]: repr(a[0])
Out[13]: '0.313767818199811'

In [14]: repr(a[1])
Out[14]: '0.169656461527218'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formatting: `print '%.17f' % a[0]` for 17 digits. If you ever have troubles with this again, google 'python float print precision'