# Why print() "cutting" float variables in python?

Tags: python

If i print a list of float contained in a list there is no problem, but if I print only one single float of this list of list, it not print all the digits!

```
listafeaturevector = [

[0.26912666717306399, 0.012738398606387012, 0.011347858467581035, 0.1896938013442868, 2.444553429782046]
,
[0.36793086934925351, 0.034364344308391102, 0.019054536791551006, 0.0076875387476751395, 3.03091214703604]
,
[0.36793086934925351, 0.034364344308391102, 0.019054536791551006, 0.0076875387476751395, 3.03091214703604]
,
[0.30406240228443038, 0.047100329090555518, 0.0049653458889261448, 0.0004618404341300081, 5.987025009738751]

]

for i in range (0,len(listafeaturevector)):
    a = listafeaturevector[i]
    print(a[0])
    print(",")
    print(a)
    for j in range (0, len(a)  ):
        print(a[j])
```

this prints all digits:

```
print(a)
```

this prints partial digits:

```
print(a[0])
```

Comment: Note that a `float` can't hold those exact values anyway; you may want `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, the `floats` are converted to string by calling the `__str__` method. This will truncate the digits.
If you wan't the exact representation, you should rather call `__repr__` method through the `repr` built-in to get the entire float representation

Another important factor here is that the precision of your floats are higher than the IEEE 64 bit representable formats. So there will be some truncation

example

```
>>> print 0.26912666717306399
0.269126667173
>>> print repr(0.26912666717306399)
0.269126667173064
>>> print("%.16f" % 0.26912666717306399)
0.2691266671730640
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the number of digits you want after the decimal point:

```
print("%.15f" % a[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that when you `print` a `list` it calls the `__str__` method of the list, which in turn calls the `__repr__` method of each of it's items. Quoting the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

> object.__repr__(self)
>   Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

So `__repr__` should try to be as close to the object as possible. So:

```
>>> repr(0.012738398606387012)
'0.012738398606387012'
>>> str(0.012738398606387012)
'0.0127383986064'
```

`list` being the model citizen that he is tries to make all of it's items seem meaningful. Which is why your numbers don't get truncated.

Using this simple test class we can observe the same behaviour:

```
class B():
    def __str__(self): return 'STR CALLED'
    def __repr__(self): return 'REPR CALLED'


>>> print(B())
STR CALLED
>>> print([B()])
[REPR CALLED]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using string formatting:

```
print(".%15f" % a[0])
```