# Python change repr floating digits

Tags: python, repr

Okay, I want to use repr() to print out a text version of a bunch of lists and nested arrays.

But I want the numbers to have only 4 decimal places not: 42.7635745114  but 32.7635.

I'd like to use repr() because of its nice ability to handle nested arrays.  Writing my own print loop is an unattractive option.

Surely there is some way to overload repr to do this?   I see there is a repr and reprlib modules but examples are really scarce, like nonexistent.

Comment: `repr` should be used *only* when you want a **precise** string representation. It's usually true that `eval(repr(x)) == x`. `str` should be used to obtain a *standard* readable representation. If you want a *custom formatting* you have to use the formatting operations (e.g. `str.format`) and specify how the output should be composed.

Comment: Not sure how well this would work, but you could try creating your own subclass of float with a different representation, and instantiating that instead when you create your data.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to overload `repr()`. The format for floats is hardcoded in the C source code.

The [`float_repr()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/55fed3eae14b/Objects/floatobject.c#l379) calls a helper function with the `'r'` formatter, which eventually calls a [utility function that hardcodes the format](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/55fed3eae14b/Python/pystrtod.c#l1057) to what comes down to `format(float, '.16g')`.

You could subclass `float`, but to only do that for representing values (especially in a larger structure) is overkill. This is where `repr` (`reprlib` in Python 3) comes in; that library is designed to print useful representations of arbitrary data structures, and letting you hook into printing specific types in that structure.

You could use the `repr` module by subclassing [`repr.Repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html#repr.Repr), providing a `repr_float()` method to handle floats:

```
try:  # Python 3
    import reprlib
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    import repr as reprlib

class FloatRepr(reprlib.Repr):
    def repr_float(self, value, level):
        return format(value, '.4f')

print(FloatRepr().repr(object_to_represent))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> import reprlib
>>> class FloatRepr(reprlib.Repr):
...     def repr_float(self, value, level):
...         return format(value, '.4f')
... 
>>> print(FloatRepr().repr([random.random() for _ in range(5)]))
[0.5613, 0.9042, 0.3891, 0.7396, 0.0140]
```

You may want to set the `max*` attributes on your subclass to influence how many values are printed per container type.

Comment: What [about this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python)

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon: this answer was a response to the *example with reprlib* part. Using `FloatRep` removes the need to subclass `float` everywhere in a nested structure just to provide sane printed output. Yes, you can subclass `float`, but *keeping* it a `float` object throughout expressions is hard (lots of magic method overriding and even then some operations will ignore those), and in a larger nested structure, bothersome.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `reprlib` module places limits on the maximum lengths of various representation (`maxdict`, `maxstring`, etc.) which may surprise someone expecting a faithful `repr` replacement.

Comment: @jpc: that's the *very first thing noted* on the module documentation page: *The `reprlib` module provides a means for producing object representations **with limits on the size of the resulting strings.***. Put differently, the whole *point* of `reprlib` is to place limits.

Comment: @jpc: as for the suggested edit: I'm always happy to provide a cross-version compatibility layer in my answers, just ask in a comment. In 2014, Python 2 was still the dominant version and I wrote too many answers to update them all. I *am* somewhat particular as to how I move answers to be Python 3 focused rather than Python 2 centric.

Comment: The size limit I pointed out was by no means a critique of your answer, just something that surprised me. As for the edit - I tried to be non-invasive. But in the end it’s ok with me, your version is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try string formatting using `return "%.4f" %(self.float)`:

```
>>> class obj:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...             self.float = value
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "%.4f" %(self.float)
... 
>>> x = obj(8.1231231253252)
>>> x.float
8.1231231253252
>>> x
8.1231
>>>
```

Comment: You are changing the data representation. If the OP is using nested arrays of floats he'd have to change all the functions that use such arrays to unwrap and re-wrap the values. It would be easier to simply use a subclass of `float` with a different implementation of `__repr__`. However I believe you should always think twice before subclassing built-ins... defining *only* `__repr__` isn't enough since every operation would keep returning the built-in `float` type (thus breaking the output).