# Why does the Python 3 string function appear to reduce precision of float?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

In a Python (3.6.7) interactive shell on Ubuntu 18, both

```
>>> n = str(3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875)
>>> print(n)
```

and

```
>>> print(3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875)
```

yield `3.14`. While

```
>>> print('3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875')
```

yields `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875`

Why is this?

Note; I am not asking why floating-point numbers lose precision, but specifically, why the use of `str(n)` and `'n'` (quotes) behave differently with `print()`.

Comment: Very few people want to see `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875` when they `print(3.14)`.

Comment: The first two are converting a number to a string, but the third doesn't involve any conversion and is just printing a string as-is

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187684/python-change-repr-floating-digits

Comment: "why the use of str(n) and 'n' (quotes) behave differently" - they're not supposed to behave the same. `str` is not supposed to be equivalent to putting quotation marks around an expression. For a super-simple example, look at what you literally wrote - you wouldn't expect `str(n)` to be `'n'` unless you had assigned `n='n'`, would you?

Comment: `int` objects and `str` objects are different, why would you expect their `__str__` methods to be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case 1 and 2, what you manipulate is a float object

```
f = 3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875

# In case 1
print(str(f))

# In case 2
print(f)
```

And `str(f)` converts the float object to a string, `print(f)` means `print(repr(f))`, `repr(f)` also converts the float object to a string.

In case 3, what you manipulate is a string object which contains 53 characters,

### What happened when convert a float object to a string?

`str(f)` and `repr(f)` call the same function [float_repr](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/08c2ba0717089662132af69bf5948d82277a8a69/Objects/floatobject.c#L316).

In function `float_repr`, if you haven't specify precision parameter, a float object will be convert to string with double-precision floating-point format.

Double-precision floating-point format gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision.

So in this case, significant decimal digits precision is 16, `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875` will be converted to `3.140000000000000`.

An clearer example:

```
>>> str(3.140000000000000123)
'3.14'

>>> str(3.14000000000000123)
'3.140000000000001'

>>> print(3.14000000000000123)
3.140000000000001
```