# Casting large int value to float with no round up

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, precision, scientific-notation

Today I found out that casting int to float have pretty interesting precision and rounding rules.
I have couple of numbers which gives me unexpected results:

```
float(1641016854000000000) -> 1.641016854e+18 (as expected)
float(1641016854000000100) -> 1.641016854e+18 (expected 1.6410168540000001e18)
float(1641016854000000200) -> 1.6410168540000003e+18 (expected 1.6410168540000002e+18)
float(1641016854000000300) -> 1.6410168540000003e+18 (as expected)
float(1641016854000000400) -> 1.6410168540000005e+18 (expected 1.6410168540000004e+18)
```

So my questions are:

1. How I can prevent rounding of the values?
2. How to get expected results instead those I have now?

Comment: `float`s have only so much precision; if you need more, use another type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increasing floating point precision in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079282/increasing-floating-point-precision-in-python)

Comment: stack**overflow** is full of information around the limitations (if they considered as such) of *float*. If you need higher precision consider: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Here is another good writeup from python: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: You simply cannot represent `1.6410168540000003e-18` within `float` precision. Remember that both exponent and base are binary numbers? Try functions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex): `float2bin` of your numbers, vary the value (add/subtract `0b1` manually) and `bin2float` back. This should explain why only `...2` and `...4` are generated, but not `...3`.

Comment: duplicate: [Why does the Python 3 string function appear to reduce precision of float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53750099/995714)

Comment: @alexfilexpo `float` can represent about  2^64 different values exactly.  `1641016854000000100` is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Python's default float type, as with most languages, can only be so precise to conserve memory. This is why you get floating point errors when working with extremely precise numbers.
A good way to avoid this is to use python's [decimal library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110065945/http://en.literateprograms.org/Arbitrary-precision_elementary_mathematical_functions_%28Python%29).