# Dirty print while printing a list in Python

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm a Python newbie and I've noticed something strange in such a basilar function as `print()`

Let the code explain. I would like to save in a list all the outliers of an observation. So I've written the following snippet:

```
#import numpy as np

def compute_outliers(obs):
    outliers=[]

    q1 = np.percentile(obs, 25)
    q3 = np.percentile(obs, 75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    print('q1: ', q1)
    print('q3: ', q3)
    lower_limit = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
    upper_limit = q3 + 1.5 * iqr

    for i in obs:
        if i < lower_limit or i > upper_limit:
            outliers.append(i)
    return outliers

outliers = compute_outliers(data)
```

Where data is a general feature (in the sense of "column") of a DataFrame object, from pandas library.

Now, if I tape

```
for i in outliers:
    print(i)
```

The outputi is ok:

```
20.0
0.0
17.6
2.7
18.9
0.0
18.0
```

While, if I type:

```
print(outliers)
```

This is the output:

```
[20.0, 0.0, 17.600000000000001, 2.7000000000000002, 18.899999999999999, 0.0, 18.0]
```

You can see the values (the third, the fourth, the fifth) are 'dirty'. I should simply use the first code for printing, but I'm curoius about how all of this works, so I would like to know WHY this happens.

**EDIT**

I think that to complete the question would be useful to know how to 'fix' this issue, so printing the list of right values. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's a well-known floating point issues and some trickery with `repr` and `str` in Python.

If you use Python 2, you can try this:

```
print(0.1 + 0.2)
# 0.3
print([0.1 + 0.2])
# [0.30000000000000004]
```

This is because `0.1 + 0.2` is in fact [not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to `0.3` in IEEE 754 floating point numbers. This is due to `0.1` is not `1/10` as the latter cannot be written as finite binary floating point number at all.

When you invoke `print` on a number, it uses [`str()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for that number. `str()` is a representation that aims on readability and it can omit some "insignificant" digits to make number more readable.

On the other hand, when you print a list, an algorithm to stringify that list uses [`repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for every item. `repr()` aims at exactness and reproducibility, so it provides all digits that are needed to reconstruct the number. It does not mean that it uses *all* the digits (e.g. `repr(0.1)` is still `"0.1"`, not `"0.1000000000000000055511151"` that can be obtained by `print("%.25f" % 0.1)`), but it can use more digits then `str` do.

EDIT. If you want more user-friendly output when print a list, you can do it manually with something like:

```
print(", ".join("{:.2f}".format(x) for x in outliers))
```

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python) for different approaches and [this site](https://pyformat.info) for more formatting options.

Comment: Hi Ilya and thank you for your explanaition, that is quite deep for my knowledge: look at the edit :)

Answer (score 3):

This effect is results from a combination of these facts:

- A `list` is a container type.
- `print(foo)` uses `str(foo)`, which calls `foo.__str__()`.
- [A container’s `__str__` uses contained objects’ `__repr__`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/674064)
- [Decimal fractions are not always precisely representable by binary floating point numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/674064)
- `float.__str__()` rounds to make the decimal representation look nice, while `float.__repr__()` tries to preserve as much precision as feasible.

Comment: Useful answer, could you also take a look to the edit?

Comment: @Bernheart I don't see any edit. Maybe it's already been rejected before I had a look?