# How to get only up to 2 float precision values of elements in a list

Tags: python, list, precision

How to get only up to 2  float precision values of elements in a list without changing the Float **type** of the elements.

```
l = [[u'NY Disability Contribution', 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.1],[u'Income Tax',387.32,387.32,387.32,193.66,0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1355.62]]
```

Output should be like

```
result = [[u'NY Disability Contribution', 2.60, 2.60, 2.60, 1.30, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 9.10],[u'Income Tax',387.32,387.32,387.32,193.66,0.00,0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1355.62]]
```

Eg:  for 2.6 ---> 2.60

I've tried like this

```
result = [[i[0]] + [float(format(j,".2f")) for j in i[1:]] for i in y]
```

but those are coming as string values

my output

```
   [[u'Contribution', '2.60', '2.60', '2.60', '1.30', '0.00', '0.00', 
   0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '9.10'],
   [u'Tax','387.32','387.32','387.32','193.66','0.00','0.00', 
   '0.00','0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1355.62']]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer: You can't....

Comment: inherit from list and rewrite the repr method. but that's tricky...

Comment: Numbers have their own internal representation. It does not matter the representation as a number as you are seeing it. If you want some special representation, they must be seen as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to display `print(my_list)` with a 2 float precision, you cannot unless:

- you inherit from `float` (or `list`) and change the `__repr__` method
- you convert elements to string as you did
- you avoid using `print(my_list)` and use a custom function to display your result

Using the answer provided in [Easy pretty printing of floats in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python), here is a possibility:

```
class prettyfloat(float):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%0.2f" % self

result = [[i[0]] + [prettyfloat(j) for j in i[1:]] for i in y]
```