# numpy set_printoptions precision ignored in list of tuples

Tags: numpy, python-3.4, precision

(Windows 7,Python 3.4.5 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 14:53:07) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)])

I was trying to neatly print some data by using np.set_printoptions(precision= and it seems to be ignored. Why?

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)

a=[[1,15.02],
[2,14.38],
[3,14.60]]

b=np.array(a)
print(b)
at=b.T
l=list(zip(at[0],at[1]))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[  1.    15.02]
 [  2.    14.38]
 [  3.    14.6 ]]
[(1.0, 15.02), (2.0, 14.380000000000001), (3.0, 14.6)]
```

Comment: Because it's not an np-array anymore and numpy's printing-mechanic is not used?

Comment: And which printing mechanic should be applied in this case?

Comment: You need to define your own i'm afraid, based on string-formatting like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567630/2320035), depending on your exact use-case.

Answer (score 1):

A problem of float :

```
In [118]:ref=decimal.Decimal('14.380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

In [119]: decimal.Decimal(14.38)
Out[119]: Decimal('14.3800000000000007815970093361102044582366943359375')

In [120]: decimal.Decimal(14.38)-ref
Out[120]: Decimal('7.815970093361102044582366943E-16')

In [121]: decimal.Decimal(14.38-2**-50)-ref
Out[121]: Decimal('-9.947598300641402602195739746E-16')
```

This show that 14.380000000000001 is the best float64 approximation of 14.38 .

to workaround this fact, you can downgrade in np.float32 :

```
In [140]:tuple(zip(*np.array(a).T.astype(np.float32)))
Out[140]: ((1.0, 15.02), (2.0, 14.38), (3.0, 14.6))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [34]: a
Out[34]: [[1, 15.02], [2, 14.38], [3, 14.6]]
In [35]: b=np.array(a, dtype=float).T
In [36]: b
Out[36]: 
array([[  1.  ,   2.  ,   3.  ],
       [ 15.02,  14.38,  14.6 ]])
In [37]: list(zip(*b))
Out[37]: [(1.0, 15.02), (2.0, 14.380000000000001), (3.0, 14.6)]
```

However if I first past `b` through `tolist`:

```
In [38]: list(zip(*b.tolist()))
Out[38]: [(1.0, 15.02), (2.0, 14.38), (3.0, 14.6)]
```

In the first case the elements of the tuple still have `np.float64` wrapper, while `tolist` extracts them all to native Python numbers:

```
In [39]: type(list(zip(*b))[1][1])
Out[39]: numpy.float64
In [40]: type(list(zip(*b.tolist()))[1][1])
Out[40]: float
```

`item` is another way of extracting the native number:

```
In [41]: list(zip(*b))[1][1]
Out[41]: 14.380000000000001
In [42]: list(zip(*b))[1][1].item()
Out[42]: 14.38
```

I can't say why the `setprintoptions` doesn't apply in the case of `np.float64`, but does with `np.array`.

As a general rule, it is better to use `tolist()` if you want to convert an array, and all its values, into a native Python list.  Operations like list and zip aren't enough.  They iterate on the first dimension of the array, but don't recursively convert the elements:

Partial conversion(s):

```
In [43]: list(b)
Out[43]: [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 15.02,  14.38,  14.6 ])]
In [44]: list(b[1])
Out[44]: [15.02, 14.380000000000001, 14.6]
```

Full conversion:

```
In [45]: b.tolist()
Out[45]: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [15.02, 14.38, 14.6]]
```

---

Apparently the formatter for `float64` shows all precision, regardless of the `set_printoptions` values:

```
In [58]: 14.380000000000001
Out[58]: 14.38
In [59]: np.array(14.380000000000001)
Out[59]: array(14.38)
In [60]: np.float64(14.380000000000001)
Out[60]: 14.380000000000001
In [61]: np.float32(14.380000000000001)
Out[61]: 14.38
```

An `np.float64(...)` object is, in many ways like a single item array, but different in subtle ways.  Usually though we don't create such an object directly.