# Count time process in nanosecond with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, time, count

I have a mongodb database, I want to count how long it takes to query the database. my code so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017') # open connection
db = client.customer

start = time.time()

# query data mongo
q = db.atweetdata.find()

stop = time.time()-start

print(stop)
```

The result shows `0.0`. It might because the time is so sort/fast or something.

How to count the process more specific to nanosecond? Thanks

Comment: try to see if 'stop > 0'

Answer (score 0):

by doing a similar test, I have no problem with this issue:

```
>>> import time
>>> start = time.time(); end = time.time();
>>> print(start-end)
-2.09808349609375e-05
```

Comment: can you tell what machine you use? linux? Mac? Windows?

Comment: @ytomo maybe your question is related to the default precision of your print function. see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566936/easy-pretty-printing-of-floats-in-python)

Comment: @ytomo OS X, Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda,  I am using.